# Expandable text element not displaying full text properly

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native

I'm trying to understand a tutorial that builds a set of panels that expand on click to reveal more text and collapse on click to hide everything but the title.

When I run on the iOS simulator, the panels are initialized open and all the text is displayed. If I collapse one of the panels and re-open it, it only displays the first two lines of text, and I cannot even scroll to view the rest of the text. If I then collapse it again, the panel seems to re-initialize itself to the correct size, displaying all of the text, before beginning the collapsing animation.

I think the issue is in toggle, but I'm not sure why the animation isn't expanding the panel to the correct height.

```
class Panel extends Component{
constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        title       : props.title,
        expanded    : true,
        animation   : new Animated.Value()
    };
}

toggle(){
    let initialValue    = this.state.expanded? this.state.maxHeight + this.state.minHeight : this.state.minHeight,
        finalValue      = this.state.expanded? this.state.minHeight : this.state.maxHeight + this.state.minHeight;

    this.setState({
        expanded : !this.state.expanded
    });

    this.state.animation.setValue(initialValue);
    Animated.spring(
        this.state.animation,
        {
            toValue: finalValue
        }
    ).start();
}

_setMaxHeight(event){
    this.setState({
        maxHeight   : event.nativeEvent.layout.height
    });
}

_setMinHeight(event){
    this.setState({
        minHeight   : event.nativeEvent.layout.height
    });
}

render(){
    let icon = this.icons['down'];

    if(this.state.expanded){
        icon = this.icons['up'];
    }

    return (
        <Animated.View
            style={[styles.container,{height: this.state.animation}]}>
            <View style={styles.titleContainer} onLayout={this._setMinHeight.bind(this)}>
                <Text style={styles.title}>{this.state.title}</Text>
                <TouchableHighlight
                    style={styles.button}
                    onPress={this.toggle.bind(this)}
                    underlayColor="#f1f1f1">
                    <Image
                        style={styles.buttonImage}
                        source={icon}
                    ></Image>
                </TouchableHighlight>
            </View>

            <View style={styles.body} onLayout={this._setMaxHeight.bind(this)}>
                {this.props.children}
            </View>

        </Animated.View>
    );
}
}
```

Comment: At least remove bindings from funtion calls that does not have custom parameter. For example `this._setMinHeight.bind(this)` --> `this._setMinHeight`

Answer (score 0):

You can use react-native package that provide this kind of facility refer this package that may help you [react-native-accordion](https://github.com/naoufal/react-native-accordion).